# Error while Building Irs-demo in corda

Tags: corda

The following error is encountered while building the irs-demo present in samples of corda-master using the reference

https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/samples/irs-demo

```
w: C:\Users\ravi\corda\testing\test-utils\src\main\kotlin\net\corda\testing\dsl\TestDSL.kt: (284, 37): 'importAttachment(InputStream): AttachmentId /* = SecureHash */' is deprecated. More attachment information is required
w: C:\Users\ravi\corda\testing\test-utils\src\main\kotlin\net\corda\testing\services\MockAttachmentStorage.kt: (48, 20): 'importAttachment(InputStream): AttachmentId /* = SecureHash */' is deprecated. Overrides deprecated member in 'net.corda.core.node.services.AttachmentStorage'. More attachment information is required
w: C:\Users\ravi\corda\testing\test-utils\src\main\kotlin\net\corda\testing\services\MockAttachmentStorage.kt: (60, 78): Parameter 'filename' is never used
e: C:\Users\ravi\corda\testing\node-driver\src\main\kotlin\net\corda\testing\node\internal\RPCDriver.kt: (138, 9): Class 'SingleUserSecurityManager' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun validateUser(p0: String!, p1: String!, p2: RemotingConnection!): String! defined in org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQSecurityManager3
e: C:\Users\ravi\corda\testing\node-driver\src\main\kotlin\net\corda\testing\node\internal\RPCDriver.kt: (141, 5): 'validateUser' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\ravi\corda\testing\node-driver\src\main\kotlin\net\corda\testing\node\internal\RPCDriver.kt: (145, 5): 'validateUserAndRole' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':node-driver:compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':node-driver:compileKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
```

I have run this with stacktrace get this. I have cloned the master repository and encountered this error when i tried to deployNodes of irs-demo using the command

> gradlew.bat samples:irs-demo:cordapp:deployNodes

Are there any prerequisites to be done before directly deploying nodes of irs-demo??

**UPDATE 1:**

Getting the issue with gradle when tried to build with corda V3.0

```
C:\demos\corda-release-V3.0>gradlew.bat install --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\demos\corda-release-V3.0\build.gradle' line: 112

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'corda-project'.
> repository not found: C:\demos\corda-release-V3.0

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'corda-project'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:199)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:204)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:666)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
```

Comment: The `master` branch is unstable. Can you try running the IRS demo against the `release-V3` branch?

Comment: hi @joel, i have tried with the release-v3, any suggestions about the error i kept in UPDATE 1??

Comment: See https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/1304 - does cloning it from git solve the issue?

Comment: hey, after looking into this reference https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/release-V3.0  i found same git clone url with master one. Does it vary or am i missing something over here?

Comment: i hope the given git clone url for  reference i kept [i.e. https://github.com/corda/corda.git] will download the same unstable master code??

Comment: After cloning, open a terminal in the folder and run ‘git checkout release-V3’ to check out the release V3 branch.

Answer (score 0):

Corda github adopts the cut-version release pattern. That means all the development is added to the master branch, which makes it very unstable.

Please always clone the stable branches that are tagged as V3, V4, and etc. (It also should be the default branch upon opening up the page)

For example: https://github.com/corda/corda is set to release/os/4.6
default